# Write an htaccess file with specific rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So basically I'm trying to write the below rules:

Assuming I have this website: `www.example.com`

1. HTTP -> redirect to -> HTTPS
2. www -> redirect to -> non-www
3. `https://example.com/xyz` -> rewrite to -> `https//example.com/post.php?id=xyz`

All these rules should be working at the same time. I tried the below sample:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: You see, we are here to _help_ fixing the issues you ran into which you cannot solve yourself. We are _not_ here to do your job for you, we are not a free support group. So you are expected to solve your issues yourself and ask for assistance here if you fail. Then you will have to include your current attempt along with a precise description of what specific issue you ran into.

Comment: @arkascha you don't even deserve a reply.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 sure I will add my tried access rules

Comment: I think you want to read the rules about how to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
> ```

Your first line looks like a typo(?) as it doesn't make sense.

Your second rule (a rewrite) is pretty much correct in order to rewrite the request to `post.php?id=<url>`. However, strictly speaking, the two conditions are in the wrong order considering the second condition is really only required for efficiency. Filesystem checks are relatively *expensive*, so you should be excluding requests for your static resources (using a regex string comparison) *before* resorting to a filesystem check.

So, *before* this rewrite you just need to add a HTTP to HTTPS *and* www to non-www redirect, which could be implemented as one or two rules.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# HTTP to HTTPS and www to non-www generic redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Rewrite requests to "post.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

`%1` in the first rule is a backreference to the last matched *CondPattern*. ie. This holds the domain name, less the `www.` subdomain (if any).

With regards to the HTTP to HTTPS redirect, this does assume the SSL cert is installed directly on your application server and you aren't using a front-end proxy that is managing your SSL cert.

If you are not expecting URLs to contain `.php` extensions then you should also consider adding this to the list of stated extensions in the `RewriteCond` directive.

Comment: @Daoud You're welcome. I should just add that it's really in regards to "efficiency" that the two `RewriteCond` directives on your existing rule were in the wrong order (they would otherwise still "work") - I've updated my answer to expand on this.